# Is it possible to open 2 links in same hyperlink on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to open 2 links in same hyperlink on mouseover.

Comment: <a href="http://test.com" onmouseover="window.open(this.href, 'child')">Open Two Links With One Click</a>

Answer (score 2):

Add "return false;" after your "window.open" command in the onclick attribute of the a tag.

```
<a href="http://test.com" onclick="window.open('http://example.com','newwin'); return false;" target="_blank">Open Two Links With One Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first set the hyperlink to blank and then use a JQuery function to make it open as many URLs as you want it to open.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="twolinks">Click Here</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a.twolinks').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://url1.com');
    window.open('http://url2.com');
});
```

Comment: Hi. If you found my answer to be helpful, I would appreciate it if you upvote and click the check mark if it answered the question. To add javascript functions to your HTML page, add an import line like this `<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` right below the `</body>` tag and also change the `src` value to another javascript file. Make sure you create a js folder and place all your js files in there. The `src` value is the path with respect to the path in which your current html page is.

Comment: It's not conventional to put actual javascript code into the onclick value. What JQuery lets you do is use the function in my answer without needing the `onclick` attribute inside the HTML tag. So remove that, create a js file, add the import line like my comment above with the current filename and directory path, and paste the JQuery code in that file and JQuery will automatically detect the click on the `<a>` tag